Error al crear un proyecto xamarim.forms

Tengo un error al crear un proyecto en Xamarin.Forms. He verificado que tengo todo instalado y los SDK necesarios, pero sigue sin funcionar. instale extensiones por cmd pero no me las reconoce que existan instaladas en la carpeta dotnet. alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor :C
